# How To Convert The Invoice Number On JDE Solution Report To Bar-code

Tags: jdeveloper, jde, jdedwards, jdepend

My project for JDE is to convert the invoice number that appear on JDE report to bar-code. Would you mind to tell me how I am able to do it? Because I am just a beginner for JDE software.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of bar code java or jde library which you include into your project. Then you use the APIs provided by the library to convert numbers to barcode. [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)
is one of hte libraries I know. However, I never used it with Blackberry.

A simple google after 'blackbaeery jde barcode' would give you plenty of more info.

Comment: Hello timo, thxz for ur suggestion.my 1 is JDE solution. But based on what i know JDE can directly convert the field to the bar code. Ufortunately i can't find related article and show me the way to do it.(T.T)

Answer (score 0):

If you install a Barcode Font you're supposed to *convert* any character into a barcode. But you should define what type of barcode you'll use.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode#Types_of_barcodes

Answer (score 0):

For 1 dimensional codes (like EAN f.e.) - you can use bar code font as recommended by 
lhoffman. - Usually you need to calculate control character, add it to your string and output it in BI Publisher with barcode font.
Second approach - is kind of workaround - generate bar code as image using third party web application and include image into report (in runtime).
f.e. create simple wrapper for library like this - http://barcode-coder.com/en/barcode-php-class-203.html 
it should receive invoice number as part of url and return image with proper bar code.
something like: http://*.*.*.*/barcode/12321312312.png
shouldn't take more than 5 lines of php. 
and include it in bi publisher like this: https://blogs.oracle.com/xmlpublisher/entry/dynamic_images
as advantage- you have more control on bar code and can use 2D bar codes.